# Graph API (api-version=1.5) : How to remove user from Role using C# .NET

Tags: c#, graph, office365

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj134103.aspx

According to the above article:

"Directory roles cannot be added or deleted using the Graph API. Updates are supported on the members navigation property only. Both add and remove are supported on this property."

I have tested "Add user to role works",  but Remove user from role does not work.

Any Code sample please?

Here is what I tried but no luck!

```
                if (retrievedRoles != null && retrievedRoles.Count == 1)
                {
                    retrievedRole = (DirectoryRole)retrievedRoles.First();

                    retrievedRole.Members.Remove(retrievedUser);
                    retrievedRole.UpdateAsync().Wait();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I delete an AppRoleAssignment using the Azure Active Directory .NET SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460012/how-do-i-delete-an-approleassignment-using-the-azure-active-directory-net-sdk/29745256#29745256)

Comment: I don't believe DirectoryRole and AppRoleAssignments are the same thing.